# Getting error when updating the Minikube installation

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Iam trying to start Minikube but it gives an error:

```
Error getting primary cp:could not find master node
```

What is the reason for this error & How to fix this error?

Comment: Here is the git [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6943)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get this error when you update your Minikube establishment;  **Minikube is as yet referring to the old documents inside $HOME/.minikube catalog**. To stay away from this error, basically **delete the .minikube directory and start Minikube again**.

You can use below commands to do the same:

```
$ minikube delete — all — purge
```

```
$ rm -rf .minikube/
```

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

Refer to the Medium [Blog](https://shashanksrivastava.medium.com/ho-to-fix-common-minikube-errors-61de8cee3469) written by Shashank Srivastava for more information about this error.